# Error compiling Handout with notes

Tags: beamer, presentations, notes, handout

I am trying to print handouts with notes from a beamer presentation.

Adding `handoutWithNotes.sty` as pointed in [Creating latex-beamer handouts with notes](https://www.guidodiepen.nl/2009/07/creating-latex-beamer-handouts-with-notes/)
does not compile in my latex file:

```
\documentclass[t,handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{handoutWithNotes} % <----- HANDOUTS NOTES
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1 with notes}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]
% \pgfpagesuselayout{1 on 1 with notes}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]
\usepackage{pgfpages}

%\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\graphicspath{{_figs/}{_figs_tikz/}{_eps/}{_sym/}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage{textpos} % para posicionar los frames en color
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
% \pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%%%---------------
% 
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.8}
% \crefname{table}{tabla}{tablas}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
%

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.text,calligraphy}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{fit} %---
\pdfsuppresswarningpagegroup=1 %---
\def\shft#1{\raisebox{1ex}}
\def\wc{6} % ancho colector
\def\hc{4} % alto colector

\tikzset{
state/.style={
       rectangle split,
       rectangle split parts=2,
       rectangle split part fill={red!80!blue!20,blue!15},
       % rounded corners,
       draw=black,  thick,
       minimum height=2em,
       text width=4cm,
       inner sep=2pt,
       text centered,
       inner ysep=5mm, %to control space in the box
       inner xsep=3mm,
       }
}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows,positioning}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\tikzset{
  every overlay node/.style={
    anchor=north west,
  },
}

\def\tikzoverlay{%
   \tikz[baseline,overlay]\node[every overlay node]
}%
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle,
% outer/progressbar=foot
]{metropolis}
%%%%---------------------
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}%,trees,shadows} 

%----------- width and color of progressbar
\makeatletter
\setlength{\metropolis@titleseparator@linewidth}{2pt}
\setlength{\metropolis@progressonsectionpage@linewidth}{2pt}
\setlength{\metropolis@progressinheadfoot@linewidth}{2pt}
\makeatother
%------------
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}

\definecolor{upctcol}{RGB}{0,84,160}

\definecolor{amari}{RGB}{230,177,1}
\definecolor{bananamania}{rgb}{0.98, 0.91, 0.71}
\definecolor{mediumseagreen}{rgb}{0.24, 0.7, 0.44}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=7}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]


\title[GdR (U.1.1.)]{Intro}
\author[/PTU]{pll\\
\texorpdfstring{\\[0.05cm]}{--}
Presentation}
\date{September 2021} 

% %%%%%%
% \mode<handout>{
% \usepackage{pgfpages}
% \pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]
% \setbeamertemplate{note page}{%
%     \fontsize{12pt}{32pt}\selectfont
%     Notes
%
%     \rule{\textwidth}{1pt} \rule{\textwidth}{1pt} \rule{\textwidth}{1pt} \rule{\textwidth}{1pt} \rule{\textwidth}{1pt} \rule{\textwidth}{1pt} \rule{\textwidth}{1pt} \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\par
% }
%
% \setbeameroption{show notes}
% }
% \makeatletter
% \def\beamer@framenotesbegin{%   at beginning of slide
%     \gdef\beamer@noteitems{}%
%     \gdef\beamer@notes{{}}% used to be totally  empty.
% }
% \makeatother
% %%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \metroset{block=fill}
    
    \begin{frame}[t]{}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    %--- Next Frame ---%
    \begin{frame}[t]{Tit 1}
        frame 1
    \end{frame}
    %--- Next Frame ---%
    \begin{frame}[t]{Tit 2}
        frame 2
    \end{frame}
    %--- Next Frame ---%
    \begin{frame}[t]{Tit 3}
        frame 3
    \end{frame}
    %--- Next Frame ---%
    \begin{frame}[t]{Tit 4}
        frame 4
    \end{frame}
    %--- Next Frame ---%
    
    \begin{frame}[t]{Tit 5}
        frame 5
    \end{frame}
    %--- Next Frame ---%
    \begin{frame}[t]{Tit 6}
        frame 6
    \end{frame}
    %--- Next Frame ---%
\begin{frame}[standout]
        % Gracias
    % \flushleft
    % Homework: p.342 \#7-21
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

I have also tested solution of beamer in [Beamer - handoutWithNotes not working properly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378521/178274):

```
\mode<handout>{
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{6 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]
\setbeamertemplate{note page}{%
    \fontsize{12pt}{32pt}\selectfont
    Notes

    \rule{\textwidth}{1pt} \rule{\textwidth}{1pt} \rule{\textwidth}{1pt} \rule{\textwidth}{1pt} \rule{\textwidth}{1pt} \rule{\textwidth}{1pt} \rule{\textwidth}{1pt} \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\par
}

\setbeameroption{show notes}
}
\makeatletter
\def\beamer@framenotesbegin{%   at beginning of slide
    \gdef\beamer@noteitems{}%
    \gdef\beamer@notes{{}}% used to be totally  empty.
}
\makeatother
```

Adding these lines before the `\begin{document}` in my MWE works fine with simple frames, but not with frames with several slides included in each one.
When there are several slides in the same frame, the above beamer solution mixes and overlays the different slides in one printed slide like this:

[image]

In this case,
the solution of [Beamer: error while making handouts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27548/178274) is to go to every slide and add `<...|handout:0> if you want to remove something or change the 0 by any slide number where that content should appear.

However, the real presentation has many frames and about five slides per frame. The presentation contains slides with itemizes `<+->` `<x-y>` slides, `\visible<x->` to add images, `\onlyslides<x->`, so it results in a complex task to make a proper handout with line notes.

It looks like the solution of adding the style `handoutWithNotes.sty` of [Creating latex-beamer handouts with notes](https://www.guidodiepen.nl/2009/07/creating-latex-beamer-handouts-with-notes/) avoids making the slide by slide differentiation with `|handout:x`.
Therefore, I would like to ask how I can compile the MWE using this style. I am using MacTex2021 TeX distribution in my computer.

Comment: Seems to work fine now with v1.3 of `handoutWithNotes`